# How to get “instant" output of “tail -f” as input?

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I want to monitor a log file, when a new log message match my defined pattern (say contain “error”), then send out an email to me.

To do that, I wrote a python script monitor.py, the main part looks like:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    if "error" in line:
        print line
```

It works well when I use `tail my.log | python monitor.py`, then I switch to `tail -f my.log | python monitor.py`, then it doesn’t work, at least not immediately.

I have done some tests,  when the new content to the log accumulate up to 8KB, then my python script can get output from tail. So I highly suspect that this is controlled by the stdin/stdout buffer size. How can I get the output immediately?

One more question, when I use `tail -f my.log` and `tail -f my.log | grep error`, why it could show me the output immediately?

Answer (score 5):

Most Linux programs will use line buffering if stdout is connecting to a TTY and full buffering otherwise. You can use [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) to force line buffering.

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f my.log | python monitor.py
```

Comment: Looking at [man stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), are we supposed to prefix `stdbuf` to `tail -f` or `python` command? or both are OK?

Comment: Thank you John, this is absolutely the right direction! But I still fail to make it work as expect, does it work for you? My stdbuf version is 8.4 and according to my blank terminal, I think my python script still can not read output from `tail -f` even using `stdbuf -oL`

Comment: @anishsane , you get any luck?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [patch to add unbuffered output to tail](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-06/msg00054.html), dating from 2008. which appears to have been [rejected](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#tail-invocation) and my own (BSD) manpage does not indicate it. Perhaps you could download [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils), apply the patch, compile tail yourself and it may still work?