# Python: have check_call output to file continously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filestream

Is it possible to get the following `check_call` procedure:

```
 logPath="log.txt"
 with open(logPath,"w") as log:
       subprocess.check_call(command, stdout = log, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )
```

to output the `stdout` and `stderr` to a file **continously**?

On my machine, the output is written to the file only after the `subprocess.check_call finished`.

To achieve this, perhaps we could modify the buffer length of the `log` filestream?

Comment: First thing: `open(logPath,  'w', 0)` for no buffering on the parent side. However, the client process may still do its own buffering which you may our may not be able to influence. I.e. if `command` buffers its output and you cannot switch the command to not buffer, you will get data in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without some OS tricks.

That happens because the output usually is **line-buffered** (i.e. after a newline character, the buffer is [flushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042849/what-does-flushing-the-buffer-mean)) when the output is a terminal, but it is **block-buffered** when the output is a file or pipe, so in the block-buffering case, you won't see the output written "continuously", but rather it will be written every 1k or 4k or whatever the block size it is.

This is the default behavior of libc, so if the subprocess is written in C and using `printf()`/`fprintf()`, it will check the output if it is a terminal or a file and change the buffering mode accordingly.

The concept of buffering is (better) explained at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html

This is done for performance reasons (see [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042849/what-does-flushing-the-buffer-mean)).

If you can modify subprocess' code, you can put a call to `flush()` after each line or when needed.

Otherwise there are external tools to force line buffering mode (by tricking programs into believing the output is a terminal):

- [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) part of the [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) package
- [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf)

Possibly related:

- [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee) (suggests use of `unbuffer`)
- [java subprocess does not write its output until it terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660280/java-subprocess-does-not-write-its-output-until-it-terminates) (a shorter explanation of mine written years ago)
- [How to get “instant" output of “tail -f” as input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162743/how-to-get-instant-output-of-tail-f-as-input/22162811#22162811) (suggests `stdbuf` usage)
- [Piping of grep is not working with tail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362450/piping-of-grep-is-not-working-with-tail/26362691#26362691) (only for `grep`)

Comment: great answer! :) absolutely :-)